# Java RMI Object/DTO transfer ClassCastException

Tags: java, rmi, classcastexception

I have got a ClassCastException when i want to get back a DTO through rmi service.
My stuff:

Module A:

```java
    @Bean
    public RmiProxyFactoryBean rmiProxyFactoryBean() {
        RmiProxyFactoryBean proxyFactory = new RmiProxyFactoryBean();
        proxyFactory.setServiceUrl("rmi://localhost:1099/FileApi");
        proxyFactory.setServiceInterface(FileApi.class);
        return proxyFactory;
    }
```

Module_B:

```java
    @Bean
    public RmiServiceExporter rmiServiceExporter(final FileApi implementation) {
        Class<FileApi> serviceInterface = FileApi.class;
        RmiServiceExporter exporter = new RmiServiceExporter();
        exporter.setServiceInterface(serviceInterface);
        exporter.setService(implementation);
        exporter.setServiceName(serviceInterface.getSimpleName());
        exporter.setRegistryPort(1099);
        return exporter;
    }
```

```java
    @Data
    public class FileDto implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 8226436902318340588L;

        private final String streamId;
        private final String name;
        private final boolean isDirectory;

    }
```

```java
    public interface FileApi {
        FileDto uploadFile(final UploadDto uploadDto);
    }
```

The problem: When i call `FileDto uploadFile(final UploadDto uploadDto);` and i want to use the result dto then i get this:

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException: class hu.teszt.FileDto cannot be cast to class hu.teszt.FileDto (hu.teszt.FileDto is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; hu.teszt.FileDto is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader @6ea914f)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy144.uploadFile(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

I tried to implement java.rmi.Remote in FileDto.class, but i get the same exception. What did i wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to the `devtools` package. See the [following issue on GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3316):

> It will happen indeed with any library that deserialize content. Caching libraries, in particular, are affected.

You can either remove the `devtools` package from your pom or don't implement the `Serializable` interface, see if that solves the issue.